# Not In query with pagination in Spring Crud repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Help me to resolve this problem,

I am using Spring Boot with Crud repository, My DB schema look like :-

1. Post(id, title, createdDate, user)
2. ReportedAbuse(id, postId, user_id)

Post table contains All post details and ReportedAbuse table contain postId and userId (if any user marks some post as abuse then this entry will be stored here)

Now I want to fetch those posts which has not been marked as abuse by current loggedIn user.

I wrote query like:-

```
public interface PostRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Long> {

        public Page<Post> findAllByUserOrderByCreatedDateDesc(Pageable pageable,
        User userId);

}
```

By using query annotation(@Query) I am unable to join these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to create the @Query thing. But if you really need @query just to do the join that does not make sense. You do the join when you create the entities. Remember you have a user object above and I have the userid as string.

```
@Query("select * from Post P, ReportedAbuse RA where p.id=RA.postId and RA.user_id= :userId" ORDER BY P.createdDate)
    public Page<Post> abusedPost(Pageable pageable,@Param("id") String userId);
```

Comment: Thanks Grinish, but this query gives all post marked as abused by current LoggedIn user, I want all those post which has not been marked as abused by current logged In user.

Comment: you can just add an additional where clause in the query that should resolve the issue.